# Can I switch cameras while recording iPhone video?

Tags: iphone, ios7, video-streaming, avcapturesession

I am developing app based on the broadcasting using vcsimplesession it is working fine while recording a video i want to use switching camera front/back. but in my scenario session will close and restart with new video so could any one please suggest me with any best solution for this issues.